# My python morse code decoder breaks when SOS is in input

Tags: python, morse-code

I'm doing a Codewars exercise and I am supposed to write a morse code decoder. I have written this so far:

```
    # ToDo: Accept dots, dashes and spaces, return human-readable message
    podzielone = morse_code.split(' ')
    alfabetmorsa = {'.-':'A', '-...':'B', '-.-.':'C', '-..':'D', '.':'E', '..-.':'F', ' ':' ', '--.':'G', '....':'H', '..':'I', '.---':'J', '-.-':'K', '.-..':'L', '--':'M', '-.':'N', '---':'O', '.--.':'P', '.-.':'R', '...':'S', '-':'T', '..-':'U', '...-':'V', '-..-':'X', '-.--':'Y', '--..':'Z', '...---...':'SOS'}
    wynikz = [alfabetmorsa.get(n, n) for n in podzielone]
    wynik = ' '.join(wynikz)
    wynik = wynik.replace('', '')[::2]
    return wynik
```

The program is supposed to recognize SOS (`...---...`) as a separate character, but it makes the O disappear in the output. If I remove `[::2]` from the 2nd-to-last line, SOS works but spaces separate every letter. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of joining on a space, you can join on an empty string and get rid of the `[::2]`:

```py
def morse_to_text(morse_code):
    podzielone = morse_code.split(' ')
    alfabetmorsa = {'.-':'A', '-...':'B', '-.-.':'C', '-..':'D', '.':'E', '..-.':'F', ' ':' ', '--.':'G', '....':'H', '..':'I', '.---':'J', '-.-':'K', '.-..':'L', '--':'M', '-.':'N', '---':'O', '.--.':'P', '.-.':'R', '...':'S', '-':'T', '..-':'U', '...-':'V', '-..-':'X', '-.--':'Y', '--..':'Z', '...---...':'SOS'}
    wynikz = [alfabetmorsa.get(n, n) for n in podzielone]
    # this is now ''.join()
    wynik = ''.join(wynikz)
    # no more [::2] needed
    return wynik
```

Comment: Thanks, but then there are no spaces between words.